# Why CSP security header blocks google maps on Iphone?

Tags: javascript, php, iphone, google-maps, content-security-policy

Do I have this header?

```
header ("Content-Security-Policy:"
                . "default-src 'none';"
                . "script-src 'self' 'nonce- $ nonce' 'strict-dynamic' * 'unsafe-inline' https://maps.gstatic.com https://maps.googleapis.com;"
                . "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;"
                . "img-src 'self' data: https://www.google-analytics.com https://im9.cz https://maps.gstatic.com https://maps.googleapis.com https: // www .smartsuppchat.com https://widget-v2.smartsuppcdn.com https://twemoji.maxcdn.com https://files.smartsuppcdn.com maps.gstatic.com * .googleapis.com * .ggpht; "
                . "form-action 'self';"
                . "base-uri 'none';"
                . "manifest-src 'none';"
                . "object-src 'none';"
                . "frame-src https://www.heureka.cz;"
                . "font-src https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com;"
                . "media-src 'self' https://widget-v2.smartsuppcdn.com;"
                . "connect-src 'self' https://bootstrap.smartsuppchat.com https://widget-v2.smartsuppcdn.com wss: //websocket-visitors.smartsupp.com https://www.google-analytics.com https : //files.smartsupp.com https://maps.gstatic.com https://maps.googleapis.com; "
                . "frame-ancestors 'self';");
```

And then this javascript, where I load google maps:

```
" src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDkzPP8cFmN7hV_va8mYdrQOrBlL9VVlwY&callback=initMap" async defer>
```

The problem I'm solving is that it doesn't load maps on my Iphone. It works everywhere else (Windows, Android). The developer tools (F12) no longer show me anything wrong. Unfortunately, I don't have an Apple and the Iphone doesn't show me anything either (there are of course no development tools).

Would anyone please know what to do with it?

Thank you

`'nonce- $ nonce'`
So I found out that iOS doesn't support nonce, which is a problem. Because he can't work with it. When I give the nonce away, it works, but it doesn't work in browsers that support CSP3. I dont know what to do with this. According to other discussions, this should be ignored and another 'unsafe-inline' rule should be used, but for some unknown reason it is not.

Would anyone know what to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of old browser that dont support CSP2*. You can add `'unsafe-inline'` as a fallback. Newer browsers will use `'nonce-$nonce'` as default. If you use CSP evaluator* to check your policy they would also suggest you add this for this reason.

References:

*https://caniuse.com/contentsecuritypolicy2

*https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/

Answer (score 0):

> 'nonce- $ nonce' So I found out that iOS doesn't support nonce, which is a problem. Because he can't work with it. When I give the nonce away, it works, but it doesn't work in browsers that support CSP3. I dont know what to do with this. According to other discussions, this should be ignored and another 'unsafe-inline' rule should be used, but for some unknown reason it is not.

1. Safari does support `'nonce-value'`, but [does not support](https://csplite.com/csp/test217/#safari) `'strict-dymanic'`. Also the `'strict-dynamic'` [overrides](https://csplite.com/csp104/#support) `'unsafe-inline'` and all host-based sources.
   Therefore when you remove `'nonce-value'`, the `'strict-dynamic'` remained does cancell `'unsafe-inline'`, `'self'` and all hosts in CSP3-compatible browsers, but not in Safari.
   Hence the effect that you observe. You have to remove `'strict-dynamic'` when you remove `'nonce-value'`, these works in pair only.
2. Your CSP has a [lot of errors](https://csplite.com/csp/check/?pl=eJydU8tO7DAM3V%2BJf4i6qYTUDg%2BxuO2SPULiCzyp0zHkUcXulAHx76TDAG0Z7kVsosbHxz71caC6rJ45HZmhx6y%2Bqbm6qjKLW7RZTdVFvceu726z9HV%2Bdn5WZVmDBnorBUetch885vXJH9aRukOM0Zp8D2kstmB7TDeWSFqKZufBkc7Vqcp7z2CwIG8pFVEbkY6r1cpBx2XLAkK61MEtgBBai9ARj9jYWXYWZ42%2FqWuClyN8cu2U3YBA9cEZhuHAKMCD3SVJPNNE7m%2Bpn36l%2FYCp1UqlNqpkB1G47zq9AZmRB2palGJ7Mclp%2FCxFBnThnkoHj0vIkEX%2Byvwi9VQtBY6RtttImpIJ0RWghYI%2FTCoF18BY9JE%2B18CBJ4O8WI6wvke9iJkI7s226aw32Ed8gDTSfU8vs4xjDi7Bzx8a5WBDMHX3%2FxNNLB28%2F9A7561DkLTJ0P3OrYH3fg%2B45qAfxiRikhAn9sxL%2FXP91Fhr4e6RpfvhS1LvnkB6tjyKejc6q19eAeUTdgk%3D#result) but looks like these should not affect Google Maps works.
   Therefore do check the [Google Map test](https://csplite.com/csp/test42/#test) in your Iphone. It's possible to select `'nonce-value'` and `'strict-dynamic'` checkboxes and check their support.
   If test works correctly, you just need to adjust your CSP.